# Как привязать get-свойство к элементу управления wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Дан класс, содержащий лист и get-свойство, которое по элементам листа высчитывает некоторое числовое значение. Также дан элемент текстбокс, к которому это свойство нужно привязать таким образом, чтобы при изменении элементов листа, изменялось и значение в текстбоксе.Как это можно реализовать?Я пытался делать стандартно через интерфейс INotifyPropertyChaneged,но не выходит, как я понимаю из-за отсутствия блока set.

Comment: `...чтобы при изменении элементов листа, изменялось и значение в текстбоксе...` при изменении листа вызывайте `PropertyChanged` с названием свойства привязанного к этому текстбоксу.

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вместо `List`, надо использовать `ObservableCollection`.
2. Пример `xaml` разметки:

```
<Window x:Class="ListTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Добавить" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Кол-во элементов" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="AddTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"/>
        <Button x:Name="AddButton" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="20" Width="70" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="20" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ResultTextBox" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="70" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path= List.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

class ListClass

```
public class ListClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string listString;

        public ListClass()
        {
            List = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }


        public ObservableCollection<string> List { get; set; }


        public string ListString
        {
            get { return listString; }
            set
            {
                if (listString != value)
                {
                    listString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises the 'PropertyChanged' event when the value of a property of the view model has changed.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }
```

`xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ListClass ListClass = new ListClass();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = ListClass;
        }


        private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string addstring;

            addstring = AddTextBox.Text;

            if(addstring != null)
            {
                ListClass.List.Add(addstring);
            }
        }

    }
```